# Ideal of Definition

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

My question refers to following excerpt:
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KQ

[image]

What is here the "ideal of definition" at the red tagged line?

Comment: An ideal of definition is an ideal whose radical is the maximal ideal.

Comment: Definition 10.58.1 [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00K4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the radical of $R$. The ideal of definition $I$ satisfies: for some $\mu, m^{\mu}\subset I\subset m$.

This is defined in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*, p.97.